# Maximal unramified extension of number field

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Suppose $k$ is a number field of finite degree. Let $M$ be its maximal unramified extension in its algebraic closure $\overline{k}$. Can somebody give me some intuition on what does $M$ look like? Also what does the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(M/k)$ look like?

Comment: It contains the Hilbert class field of the Hilbert class field of the ... Here it is [shown](https://mathoverflow.net/a/58195/84768) that for any finite group $G$ there is some extension $E/F$ unramified Galois with Galois group $G$.